# zte voice modem problem

Tags: modem

we are using zte usb modem. we try to call by AT command (ATD) successfully. But there is no sound when remote device answered.
Does anyone have any idea?

---

My problem was associated with ZTE usb modem.
I solved the problem.
i can receive and send voice separately to voice port now. But i can not get clean sound like WCDMA UI.
how can i receive and send data with high quality?

Please look at my source code. [http://serv7.boxca.com/files/0/z9g2d59a8rtw6n/ModemDial.zip]

Does anyone now where is my error?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Not all zte usb modems supports voice, to detect if modem supports check for ZTE voUSB Device in your ports list.

b) If port present, voice will go through it in pcm format, with 64kbps frequency (8000 samples per sec, 8 sample size).

In your own program, you should read audio stream from there.
stream is additionaly encoded with [g.711](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711#G.711_.CE.BC-Law), so you need to decode it before sending to audio device

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common to shut off the speaker after connection. Try sending `ATM2`, that should make the speaker always on.

[Basic hayes command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#The_basic_Hayes_command_set):

> M2
>   Speaker always on (data sounds are heard after CONNECT)

Comment: I send ATM2, but same results. I can't use data transfer. So i can't receive and send voice.

Comment: Ah, you want to make a voice call? Have you enabled voice mode, by running `AT+FCLASS=8`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set#Entering_voice_mode

Comment: Yes, i want to make a voice call. :-) i use AT+FCLASS=? command. and there is only [0,1] interval. So i can't set AT+FCLASS=8. i can set only 0 or 1.

Comment: That does indeed look like you have a non-voice modem on your end.

Comment: But i install WCDMA UI program and it can make voice call. But i want to call from my own visual c++ program.

Comment: The UI program might use the hardware in a non-standard way. I suggest you take an usb sniffer and examine what the ui program does:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but usb sniffer didn't help me. Do you know any program like WCDMA UI ?

Comment: My problem was associated with ZTE usb modem. I solved the problem. i can receive and send voice separately to voice port now. But i can not get clean sound like WCDMA UI. how can i receive and send data with high quality?

Please look at my source code: http://serv7.boxca.com/files/0/z9g2d59a8rtw6n/ModemDial.zip

Do you now where is my error?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Ramil how did you solve ZTE usb modem issue? Please share us

Comment: @atiqkhaled i used it in the past for one project, sorry i can't remember about it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use asterisk's chan_dongle module on ZTE MF180 Datacard model with activated voices abilities.

Originally chan_dongle using raw PCM format on voice data.
But i was discover, that ZTE using ulaw format on sending and recciving voice data.

You can get voice data and save file in this format for learn by using standard Asterisk's Record(filename:ulaw) command in dialplan.

My voice data, dumped from ZTE modem in the same format.
I check it. ZTE dumped data was successefully played by Asterisk's command Playback(dumped)

Comment: Hello Jack. Do you have any updates on chan_zte implementation? Are you going to release it on public?